# Connect remote via putty

Tags: networking, ssh

How to connect with putty to a ubuntu 11.04 server which is connected to the internet through a router configured with static specifications?

I have ssh server installed, and when i try to connect from my windows with putty to my remote server i get Network error : Connection timed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure port forwarding in your router to you SSH server.

Comment: I have configure port forwarding and is working. Thank you.